# how to get the index number of my Tumblr posts when in Infinite Scroll

Tags: callback, indexing, tumblr, infinite-scroll, posts

```
$('#content').infinitescroll({
        binder: $(window),
        debug: true,
        itemSelector : ".post",
        navSelector  : "#pagination",
        nextSelector : "#next-page"

        },function(arrayOfNewElems){  

    });
```

basically, I want to display the number my Tumblr posts. I have made different attempts but each time the index numbering starts again from 0 after the new content is loaded. How can I make the number a continuation from the previously loaded posts.

what kind of function should i be invoking in

function(arrayOfNewElems){

});

this is the plugin im using

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
var totalPosts = null;

$.ajax({
    url: "http://[BLOG NAME HERE].tumblr.com/api/read/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        totalPosts = results['posts-total'];
        alert(totalPosts);
    }
});
```

Needs jQuery but can be run before the document is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

why u need to get the index number os ur posts? i think this is also can work

[Infinite-scrolling with proto.jp](http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling)

http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling

Comment: omg f*ck codysherman. thats for ppl that want one swift copy paste. I want to index number the posts as a style choice i guess.